# Bottom sheet instead of dropdown in mobile app

Tags: mobile, dropdown, app

In my mobile app project I have several dropdown lists. I converted some of them to radio buttons (<5 selection options). I wonder what I should do with the rest (choosing car brand, car model, fuel, bodywork, etc.). I'm thinking of bottom sheets instead of drop-down lists, I've seen this solution in several mobile apps (e.g. Strava).
Thank you.

Comment: Any mockup, please?

Comment: Please include a mockup of what you have, as @Danielillo suggested. It could also help to include the app you're referring to. Perhaps the app has issues, or it may not be suitable for your case, leading you to consider a bad example. I mention this because, unless it's a very specific implementation, a bottom sheet is not appropriate for what you describe.